# Seeking a C# online tutor

Tags: c#

Does anybody know some websites who offers online tutoring for C#? I am particularly seeking one-on-one tutoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On books for beginners i'd recommend the [galileo-openbooks](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/csharp/)

Comment: ... if you're fluent in German.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Inner Workings](http://www.innerworkings.com/solutions/developer).

They offer self-paced .NET training to developers as an add-in to Visual Studio. The code is checked against provided solutions, so you can gain insight into different areas of the framework. Whilst it's not quite an *online* tutor, the training provided is a good start.

Comment: this one sounds good:-)thanks maybe I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

If you need online tutor help you can contact student.support@live.com which was really helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MSDN Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa740375.aspx) on Visual C#.

Comment: hi JP the site only offers I think materials for learning C# but not somebody who can teach C# online.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://www.functionx.com/csharp/)

You can check this and some other books for learning...

IMO rather than taking online tutor, it will be more fruitful if you have a mentor to guide you...if not you can ask questions here and learn from it...but it is personal taste

Sharing my learning experience, it is best to learn yourself (I am also learning C/C++) and then there should be someone to answer your confusion/questions and SO is the best place for that :)

Comment: thanks a lot. i think they only offer online materials to study but not to teach.

Comment: That's true. but I think I'm more productive if I have somebody to ask questions right away where I can interact and somebody who could say my progress.